# EF4 Repository Pattern problems injecting repository into service .Cannot seem to get it right

Tags: entity-framework-4, moq, repository-pattern

I am finding difficult to test EntityFramework 4 .I am using it using the database first approach,too late now to move to poco.Needed to deliver pretty quickly,no time to learn properly as usual.

I have implemented the repository pattern with unit of work but I am finding difficult to inject a repository into my Service layer so that I can test the behaviour of my business layer  service ,validation etc... without hitting the db.
but I am incurring in many little problems.

1. In order to inject the Repository into the service(constructor) the calling layer need to have a reference to the DAL (EF Entities) .    I dont want this
2. If i have many repositories EG CustomerRepository ,EmployeeRepository than I need to have as many constructors as repositories so that I can inject the repository.

   3.Not sure where to go from here. I have not found any example on the net where they  inject the repository into the service using EF4. All the examples I have seen they mock the repository on it's own,which is not good to me.

I need to test my service layer/BizLayer without hitting the database.

The all thing is just not testable and adds so many dependencies and problems.

Noddy example I have put together

```
public class DepartmentServiceLibrary
{
    private readonly IDepartmentRepository _departmentRepository;

    public DepartmentServiceLibrary(IDepartmentRepository  departmentRepository)
    {
        _departmentRepository = departmentRepository;
    }

    public List<DepartmentDto> GetDepartments()
    {
        return DeparmentBiz.GetDepartments();
    }

    private DeparmentBL _departmentBiz;
    private DeparmentBL DeparmentBiz
    {
        get
        {
            return _departmentBiz ?? new DeparmentBL(_departmentRepository);
        }
    }
}
```

//internal class

```
internal class DeparmentBL
{
    private readonly IDepartmentRepository _departmentRepository;

    public DeparmentBL(IDepartmentRepository departmentRepository)
    {
        _departmentRepository = departmentRepository;
    }

    public List<DepartmentDto> GetDepartments()
    {
        using (var ctx = new AdventureWorksContext())
        {
            var uow = new UnitOfWork(ctx);
            _departmentRepository.UnitOfWork = uow;
            var query = _departmentRepository.GetAll();

            return query.Select(dpt => new DepartmentDto
                                           {
                                               DepartmentId = dpt.DepartmentID,
                                               Name = dpt.Name,
                                               GroupName = dpt.GroupName
                                           }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

The following TestMethod requires me to add a ref to the dal which defeats the point

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Should_be_able_to_call_get_departments()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IDepartmentRepository>();
        var expectedResult = new List<Department>();  //Dependency to DAL as Department is a EF Entity generated by EF.

        mock.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Returns(expectedResult);
        var companyService = new MyCompanyBL(mock.Object);  //InternalVisibileTO
        var departments = companyService.GetAll();
        //assert removed for brevity
```

Any suggestions or examples out there that shows how to do it?
thanks

```
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is - since you're not using POCOs, all your layers will have a reference to your DAL.

Without POCOs, you use code generation, which means EF creates the model classes in the Model.edmx.designer.cs file.

**An option** (haven't tried this - off the top of my head) is to manually project the EF entities into DTOs.

So your Repository might do this:

```
public List<OrderDTO> GetOrdersForCustomer(int customerId)
{
   return _ctx.Orders
        .Where(x => x.CustomerId == customerId)
        .ToList()
        .Select(x => new OrderDTO { // left to right copy });
}
```

The OrderDTO class could be in a separate assembly, which the repository references, as well as your other projects. So the other projects would work off the DTO assembly, and wouldn't require a reference to the Repository.

But here you're projecting into classes everywhere (basically doing POCO, but manually, and with more work) left to right copying of properties - very painful.

However, that is an option.

Honestly - **it does not take long** to move to POCOs.

There is a T4 template which will generate the POCOs for you - you could be up and running in a matter of minutes.

And since you're already using dependency injection and repository, you should either bite the bullet and change to POCOs, or keep the reference to the DAL.

Comment: just confirmed my fears.Do I need to learn t4.Everything I do I must be able to explain. I will give it a go

Comment: With poco I suppose you turn of code generation and use the t4 templates.How about stored procedures,complextypes etc.. how deal with them in poco.Do you generate them?

Comment: @user231465 - here is the T4 POCO Generator: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313. You do not need to "learn" T4 per se. Just install it, let it generate your POCO's - and move the generated POCO's to a seperate assembly.

Comment: And yes you can still create stored procs, complex types. The only problem i've found is you can't "generate" complex types. You have to manually create them - not a big deal. Maybe there is a template for that too.

Comment: And BTW - i use Repository, DI, EF4, POCO's, SPROC's in my current project. All works fine - so rest assured, people have done this and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar in terms of code can be seen here in [GitHub](https://github.com/chiranjeebghosh/asp.net-mvc-sol-arch)
and detail explanation can be found in [TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39621.asp-net-mvc-solution-architecture-project-with-async-repository-pattern-by-service-having-dependency-injection-by-unity-page-1.aspx)